# How do i get a hprof on a Citrix server?

Tags: java, citrix, hprof

I need to capture a hprof for a Java app that is running on Citrix.

So the process is on the server but the UI is on the client machine. I can attach to the javaw.exe on the server, using VisualVM, but i am unable to capture a heap dump (gives me an error message) and the 'Profiling' tab is missing from VisualVM.

Anyone know what i need to do to get the hprof from a process which is being virtualuzed over 
Citrix like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used hprof, but I do do debugging and troubleshooting in Citrix environments. Things I would check/try are:

- Ensure you're setup as a local admin on the Citrix machine.
- Get the Citrix admin to publish a desktop for you and install VisualVM on the Citrix machine. Then start a desktop session using Citrix Receiver and run VisualVM and the Java app together in the same desktop session.

Comment: You are right. We needed to get VisualVM running in the same session as the Java app. After publishing VisualVM in Citrix, we ran it on the client machine where the java app was also running. The java app showed under the local node and we were able to capture heap dumps.